# Windows 7 Netgear WNDR4000, adapter issues

Tags: windows-7, drivers, internet-connection, wired-networking

I'm running Windows 7 and using a Netgear WND4000.

I cannot seem to connect to the Internet. When I troubleshoot it, I get the following error:

> There might be a problem with the driver for Local Area Connection Adapter, try running in admin mode to fix it.

I do this, then I get another message saying the wired network adapter is experiencing problems. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the drivers, and rebooting, but still have no connection.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include details about when this started.  If possible try the machine on a different router or network. I'm assuming you are using a wired connection, are you able to connect using WiFi or vice versa?